# IPC mechanism in android jar library via AIDL file

Tags: java, android

is there any way to compile android AIDL files into android jar libraries? i want that my jar library that lives into an android app, can directly send data to another android application via IPC. is this possible? i do this in two regular android apps and they connect each other via IPC but now i want to an android library connects to another app.

when we user an AIDL file in android project, after building of project the compiler creates a java class in gen folder and that class uses to IPC mechanism. but android libraries doesn't have any gen folder! is this possible to use IPC inside an android jar library at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont make common project as a jar, make it as an android library project: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

Comment: i do it as an android library project. but my question is that is that possible that i communicate with another application via an AIDL file inside an android library jar file?

Comment: when we user an AIDL file in android project, after building of project the compiler creates a java class in gen folder and that class uses to IPC mechanism. but android libraries doesn't have any gen folder! is this possible to use IPC inside an android jar library at all?  please help me. this waste my 3 days! how can create jar file from my code to compile AIDL to library? mybe problem was there! thanks

Comment: 3 days? hint: goto <project_root>/bin/classes and see what is there

Comment: yes 3 days! i have to send some data from android library to another app that i created before, but i cant! there is no any content on the web about that!  you know, in library project, when i want to import AIDL into my code by import com.example.myaidl; , eclipse doesnt resolve it! in native android app everything works great. please help me to solve this problem, after that i think its necessary to write an article about that somewhere in the web! i need to be sure that an android library can send data via IPC mechanism or not? if im sure, i can try more... thanks

Comment: did you check bin/classes folder?

Comment: so your problem is gone if you have all the classes including generated AIDL class

Comment: but i have the problem... so what can i do? i tested many ways. if i create a regular android application and put my library files in the src folder, the bin folder contains my classes. if i create a a java library project and put my classes in src folder, the AIDL file doesn't resolve in the surce code. in connectiong two regular android application i dont have any problem. but in this case im confused! it doesn't work! :(

Comment: do you have generated class or not? if you have that class it will be in the jar as well

Comment: so why do you say you have **runtime** error only now? post your aild interface both from the service and the client side

Comment: i solved my problem :) thank you for your advice's. when i export jar file in eclipse i only select src folder and gen folder and it works! thank you thank you  ;)